# Почему при смене framework функция выгрузки excel сбила форматирование?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Помогите, пожалуйста.
Никак не пойму

```
private void cellB(int size, bool bold, int x, int y, string val)
{
    objrange = worksheet.Cells[x, y];
    if (objrange != null)
    {
        range = (Range)objrange;
        range.Font.Name = "Arial";
        range.Font.Size = size;
        range.Font.Bold = bold;
        range.Value2 = val;
        range.Borders.LineStyle = 1;
        range.NumberFormat = "### ##0,00";
        range = null;
    }
}
```

Тут раньше делал нормально нумберформат. Теперь числа 1 аля 001 стали, в общем толи делиметр умер, толи я вообще с ума сошел :(

перевел с framework 2.0 на framework 4.0

Answer (score 1):

При откате бэйкапа и переходе с 2.0 на 3.5 всё стало нормально(это пришлось делать для interop.Excel).
При использовании OpenXML достаточно указать верный разделитель.